# $\log^2 (x^2) + \log (x-1) = 0$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to solve the equation $\log^2 (x^2) + \log (x-1) = 0$ but all I could do is to show that $1 < x < 2$. Wolfram Alpha says that $x = 1.508554...$, this is good, but I really want to write $x$ with some explicit expression, not numerical approximation.

This problem came from a group of friends, no one knows how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\log(\log(x^2))$ or $(\log(x^2))^2$?

Comment: I would assume the latter.

Comment: @vadim123 The decimal expansion agrees with the latter.

Comment: I am not sure if that is even possible. Let's hope someone smarter than me replies

Comment: If Wolfram Alpha doesn't give a closed-form nice result, then I probably won't be able to figure it out.

Comment: This equation does not have a solution which can be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions and operators.

Comment: $\log^2(x^2) = ( \log(x^2))^2$.

Comment: @Mathematician171 How do you to proof your statement?

Comment: Takes $(1 + 2)/2 = 1.5$ as a guess and use Newton-Rapson. In $\large\tt two$ steps it leads $\sf to 1.50855$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known closed-form solution for equations like this one. Let's simplify it:
$$\log^2x^2+\log(x-1)=0$$
$$\log x^2\cdot\log x^2=-\log(x-1)$$
$$\log x^{2\log x^2}=\log\dfrac1{x-1}$$
$$x^{4\log x}=\dfrac1{x-1}$$
$$x^{-4\log x}=x-1$$
We have exponential and logarithmic function on LHS and linear function on RHS. When we have linear and exponential or logarithmic function in same equation we must use Lambert W function. Only equation which can be solved using Lambert W function is
$$a^{f(x)}+bf(x)+c=0$$
if we can find $f^{-1}(x)$ where $a,b,c$ are constants. Equation $\log^2x^2+\log(x-1)=0$ cannot be reduced to this form, so there are no closed-form solution.